# What can I do if the tenant has vacated the apartment but didn't pay last month bill for electricity?

Tags: rental-property, india

I have an apartment which I gave to 3 students on rent. This month they vacated the apartment without paying the last month electricity bill. I have no written agreement but did police verification. So, what can I do now? Can I lodge a fraud complaint against them?

Comment: Did you ask them to pay the bill?  It's not clear from the details given that they are operating in bad faith.

Comment: Why is the electricity account not in the tenant's name in the first place?

Comment: @DaleM, one obvious reason is to reduce the paperwork when the tenant moves out and when the next one moves in.

Comment: @Mark - suit yourself, I'd rather have slightly more paperwork *and* more money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to sue them for the money.  You may decide that the cost and stress of doing so is not worth it, and just write off the cost.

In future you should require a deposit (if you don't already), and not return it until you have checked that the final utility bills have been paid.  (I am assuming there was no deposit, or that you have returned it already; if not, you can pay the electricity company out of that deposit.)